# How to import vcard with photo as link into outlook?

Tags: outlook, photo, vcf-vcard

Is there any special format I've to use when I want a photo with a link in a vCard to be imported into Outlook contacts?

```
PHOTO;VALUE=URL;TYPE=JPEG:http://www.contoso.com/phonebook/images/123456.jpg
```

When I use this format Outlook doesn't accept the image. Does Outlook accept photos with links or do I have to encode the image into BASE64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook does not handle vCards with links to photos. The image must be included in the file itself.
Are you importing vCards programmatically?

Comment: Thank you Dmitry!
We provide vCards in our intranet to download and import into Outlook for mobile devices.